# Javascript OOP Method return " is not a function"

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

As new on JS developpment, I've started the OOP which from my point of view is the more dificult but also the most intersting part of JS.

There is my code :

```
var calc = function(num1, num2){
  this.num1 = num1;
  this.num2 = num2;
  this.addNum2 = function(number){
    this.num2 = number;
  }
}
```

And now, I'm trying to use the `function addNum2`to set the num2 with

```
calc.addNum2(24)
```

I got this return:

> VM495:1 Uncaught TypeError: calc.addNum2 is not a function

I'm just here to understand how it works so any help would be precious.
Thank you all!

Comment: `calc` is a *construtor* which constructs an object which has the method `addNum2`. You use it as `new calc(a, b)` first…

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke function with [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

```js
function calc(num1, num2) {
  this.num1 = num1;
  this.num2 = num2;
  this.addNum2 = function(number) {
    this.num2 = number;
  }
}

let newCalc = new calc()
newCalc.addNum2(2)
console.log(newCalc.num2)
```

---

Or you need to return `this` from function

```js
function calc(num1, num2) {
  this.num1 = num1;
  this.num2 = num2;
  this.addNum2 = function(number) {
    this.num2 = number;
  }
  return this
}

let newCalc = calc()
newCalc.addNum2(2)
console.log(newCalc.num2)
```

---

> i would like to do let's say : `newCalc.addNum2(4).mutiply(5);`

```js
function calc(num1, num2) {
  this.num1 = num1;
  this.num2 = num2;
  this.addNum2 = function(number) {
    this.num2 = number;
    return this
  }
  this.multiply = function(number){
    this.num2 = this.num2 * number
    return this
  }
  return this
}

let newCalc = calc()
newCalc.addNum2(2).multiply(3)
console.log(newCalc.num2)
```

Comment: You're missing the arguments to `calc`…

Comment: @deceze i left intentionally so i can show the function is actually changing the value. but yes i could have used different values too

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! My main concern was, is it possible to call "calc" without giving him parameter, and set it later with "addNum" and I can see it's possible! Thanks so much!

Comment: @CodeManiac Just last question, if for example i would like to do let's say : newCalc.addNum2(4).mutiply(5);
In that case, how shall i structure it?

Comment: @Kevkeev13 You need to return `this` from functions so you can chain methods. so you need to return `this` from both `addNum2` and `multiply` function. see the last snippet you can do something like this